# Valid way of putting a totals row above the column headers in a table

Tags: html, html-table

The question is if there is a valid (logical) way to construct a table in HTML that has a totals row above the column headers.  So essentially it would be something like:

```
Date      | [Total number of dogs] | [Total number of cats] | [Total number of snakes]

                   Dogs            |         Cats           |           Snakes

[Date1]   |     [DogsThatDay       |       [CatsThatDay]    |        [SnakesThatDay]
```

etc etc...

Normally the dogs cats snakes would go into the thead, but I want the totals to be above.

It doesn't seem correct to put my totals into thead and then put the column headers into the actual tbody as just another row. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple rows within a "thead" tag:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>[Total number of dogs]</th>
        <th>[Total number of cats]</th>
        <th>[Total number of snakes]</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>[Date1]</th>
        <th>Dogs</th>
        <th>Cats</th>
        <th>Snakes</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
     ...content
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

After table has been loaded, use js to load the counts into your header columns.